# Limit AWS EC2 Instances to Access S3 Buckets in the Same Region ONLY

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I need to download terabytes data from S3 buckets in EC2 instances frequently. I would like to avoid unnecessary data transfer cross regions.

I am aware of
[Example 1: Granting a user permission to create a bucket only in a specific Region](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/amazon-s3-policy-keys.html#condition-key-bucket-ops-1). I tried the following:

```
  InstanceRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Action: sts:AssumeRole
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: ec2.amazonaws.com
        Version: "2012-10-17"
      Policies:
        - PolicyDocument:
            Statement:
              - Action: s3:*
                Condition:
                  StringLike:
                    s3:LocationConstraint: sa-east-1
                Effect: Allow
                Resource: arn:aws:s3:::*
            Version: "2012-10-17"
          PolicyName: s3
  InstanceInstanceProfile:
    Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
    Properties:
      Roles:
        - Ref: InstanceRole
  Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      IamInstanceProfile:
        Ref: InstanceInstanceProfile
      ......
    DependsOn:
      - InstanceRole
```

However, all S3 buckets deny my access from the EC2 instance launched in `sa-east-1`, no matter if the buckets are in `sa-east-1` or not.

Is there a complete and working example for my case?

Comment: Not an answer, but `LocationContraint` only apply to some bucket level API calls, like CreateBucket. Doesn't apply to GetObject for example (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_GetObject.html). Maybe look into https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html#condition-keys-requestedregion or VPC Endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

`LocationConstraint` only works for `CreateBucket` and `CreateAccessPoint`. See: [Actions, resources, and condition keys for Amazon S3 - Service Authorization Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazons3.html)

The easiest approach would probably be:

- Add an `Allow` policy that grants all relevant access to S3, then
- Add a `Deny` policy specifically for `s3:CreateBucket` where `s3:LocationConstraint` is *NOT* `sa-east-1`

Try to avoid granting `s3:*` because this also grants permission to **delete every bucket and all objects** in the account!

Comment: John, thank you very much for the `Deny` policy.

Answer (score 0):

Thank [bgdnlp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11033167/bgdnlp) a lot of the suggestion. Following the link [aws:RequestedRegion](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html#condition-keys-requestedregion)
 therein, the problem is solved by replacing `Condition` by

```
"Condition": {
    "StringEquals": {
        "aws:RequestedRegion": ["sa-east-1"]
    }
}
```